# "Sequelize is not a constructor" while initializing Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs

I'm trying to setup Sequelize using ES6 in my code, but getting this error:

> TypeError: _sequelize.Sequelize is not a constructor

Here's my *sequelize.js* file:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

import config from './config';

const db = new Sequelize({
  ...config.database,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
  },
});

export default db;
```

and here's the *.babelrc* file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "minify"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./", "./src"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think Sequelize is the default export? Try removing the curly braces from the import. i.e. `import Sequelize from 'sequelize';`

Comment: @evolutionxbox already tried couple of approaches like `import Sequelize from 'sequelize';`, `import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';` but to no avail

Comment: It's how they import it [in their docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html). Have you installed the module?

Comment: I have installed it on numerous other projects. But working with it in ES6 for the first time.

Comment: Could `module-resolver` be causing the issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox great! it seems so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @evolutionxbox's suggestion. The problem was with the babel configuration itself. Removed the `module-resolver` to make it work. *.babelrc* looks like this now:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "minify"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me working with es6 I do

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const db = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  flags: '-FOUND_ROWS',
  logging: false
});
```

My babel.config.js file is

```
const presets = [
    "@babel/preset-env",
];
const plugins = [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
    [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        {

            "regenerator": true
        }
    ]
]
module.exports = {presets, plugins};
```

Comment: The problem was with the `module-resolver` in the *.babelrc* file. Removed it to make it work.